# specifying goal in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am creating a new maven project with `pom.xml` as below:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>firstRestlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>restlet1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>restlet1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
<repository>
   <id>maven-restlet</id>
   <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
   <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
</repository> 
</repositories>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem which i am facing is that target war file is not getting generated.
On eclipse console after i ran this `pom.xml` what i found was goals missing in `pom.xml`.

**ECLIPSE CONSOLE MESSAGE:**

```
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Please tell me how to specify goals in `pom.xml`.

Also tell me how to create RESTLET project using maven as build tool.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Please tell us what command you are running and what the output on the console is.

Comment: In the run configuration specify the goal as `install`

Answer (score 87):

The error message which you specified is nothing but you are not specifying goal for maven build.

you can specify any goal in your run configuration for maven build like clear, compile, install, package.

please following below step to resolve it.

1. right click on your project.
2. click 'Run as' and select 'Maven Build'
3. edit Configuration window will open. write any goal but your problem specific write 'package' in Goal text box.
4. click on 'Run'

Comment: This did work for me, but the error message and its fix seem so vague and unncessary

Comment: How to add the goal in pom.xml  to make it available in "Run as" option of eclipse. 
ex : to make a validate goal available(Maven validate).

Comment: Good question. I can not see option at this moment But i will check it and comment it here. Thanks

Comment: What to enter in the "Profiles" text field?

Answer (score 31):

I've bumped into this question because I actually wanted to define a default goal in pom.xml. You can define a default goal under build:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
...
</build>
```

After that change, you can then simply run `mvn` which will do exactly the same as `mvn install`.

Note: I don't favor this as a default approach. My use case was to define a profile that downloaded a previous version of that project from Artifactory and wanted to tie that profile to a given phase. For convenience, I can run `mvn -Pdownload-jar -Dversion=0.0.9` and don't need to specify a goal/phase there. I think it's reasonable to define a `defaultGoal` in a profile which has a very specific function for a particular phase.

Answer (score 17):

You should always give an argument to your maven command. Normally this is one of the lifecycles. For example:

```
mvn package
```

Package will create jars, wars, ears etc.

For more phases and their meaning, see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 9):

**1**.right click on your project.
**2**.click 'Run as' and select 'Maven Build'
**3**. edit Configuration window will open. write any goal but your problem specific write 'package' in Goal 
**4** user settings: show your maven->directory->conf->settings.xml 
for example;  C:\maven\conf\settings.xml

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Terminal
2. Do `mvn clean install`

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: But what if I want to debug to hit the breakpoints?

Answer (score 5):

Add the goal like -

```
 <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <!-- Source directory configuration -->
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this exception, and found out that I forgot to add a Main.
Check out if you have `public static void main(String[] args)` correctly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

just add the below lines to your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same Issue after run my build.

The error message tell us to specify your goal

[image: Jenkins Issue related to goal for build]

So I specify the goal Ex:-test.

Now It's running fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path of maven under Global setting
like

```
MAVEN_HOME

/user/share/maven
```

and make sure the workbench have permission of read, write and delete
"777"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when trying to run spring boot from the command line...

`mvn spring-boot:run`

I accidentally mis-typed the command as...

`mvn spring-boot run`

So it was looking for the commands... run, build etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with this error message and solution was pretty simple. It was just fixed by specifying a working directory at my IntelijIdea configuration and specifying a goal as the paramameter opposite 'Command-line param'.