# Maven error when using command line to execute java program

Tags: java, bash, maven, maven-2

When I run my Maven project from Netbeans everything works properly. However, when i use the command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Main.Laucher" -Dexec.args=$args1 $args2 $args3
```

I obtain this error:

```
     [ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Invalid task '1': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or
 pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Total time: < 1 second
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 21 12:06:23 CEST 2014
     [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/491M
```

The maven version is :

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_51
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-58-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

In `pom.xml` i have `exec-maven-plugin`:

> ```
>      <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.1</version>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>java</goal>
>         </goals>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>     <configuration>
>          <mainClass>simulation.amazon.Laucher</mainClass>
>     </configuration>
>     </plugin>
> ```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: have you add the `exec-maven-plugin` in you pom.xml?

Comment: Yes i have. I edited my poste

Comment: A bit too late, but I found this very similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108374/maven-how-to-run-a-java-file-from-command-line-passing-arguments

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure `exec-maven-plugin` plugin your `pom.xml` for example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <key>myproperty</key>
              <value>myvalue</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: Even if i add the correct plugin, i obtain the same error. I edited the original poste

Comment: The error now is just: `Invalid task '1': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal`

Comment: if your project is jar file, then you should configure as jar in pom.xml and running command also by jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the plugin as a dependency which is incorrect. You should add it as a plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.co dehaus.mojo</groupId> 
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </plugin> 
     </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't really see how it is working in NetBeans but this configuration is definitely required for it to work via the command line.

Comment: Even if i add the correct plugin, i obtain the same error. I edited the original poste

Comment: The error now is just:
`Invalid task '1': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal`

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with my maven project in IntelliJ and I found an alternative way to make it work, even without the exec-maven-plugin. I was able to build the project by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852950/specifying-goal-in-pom-xml) answer and including a default goal in the following pom.xml file:

```
<defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Then, even though the project could be build, whenever I used command line parameters in the run configuration, I had the same issue that the first argument was considered the lifecycle's name.
So, instead of defining a new **Maven** run configuration, I chose a normal **Application**. After selecting the main class and defining the program parameters as well, everything worked.

Similarly, if you must run your java program from the command line, you can avoid this error by first building your project and then calling your main class.
I specifically did:

```
mvn package
java -cp target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar run.MyMain "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

and it worked fine. It looks like a sufficient workaround in comparison to

```
mvn exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=run.MyMain "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

and Intellij's maven configuration that might show unexpected errors.