# Jira plugin: Specify lifecycle phase or a goal in atlassian pom.xml

Tags: maven, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have build a starter atlassian jira plugin with command:
`atlas-create-jira-plugin`. The pom.xml was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>This is the xxx:xxx plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>

                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            xxx.api,
                        </Export-Package>

                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                            *
                        </Import-Package>

                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.13.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Now when I run on it: `atlas-mvn clean` then I get error:

> Unknown lifecycle phase "${mavenPluginName}=$mavenPluginName". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:.

How can I specify the goal?

I tried this solutions:
[specifying goal in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852950/specifying-goal-in-pom-xml)
but they didn't help cuz my problem is about atlassian.

Answer (score 1):

You must run `atlas-install-plugin` first.