# Maven plugins are not downloading or resolving when I create a new project

Tags: java, maven

I am very new to maven was about to start learning spring with maven but when I created my first project with maven in eclipse this error occurred and I think maven plugins are not getting downloaded. I have tried several solutions from stackoverflow but nothing worked.

**Console Window is like :-**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.097 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-01T21:17:39-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

**Error window is like this:-**

*Please see this screenshot for exact information of errors.*

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNhpH.png)

**POM.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.anuragr07</groupId>
  <artifactId>springpractice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**Solutions tried so far:-**

1. Installing maven using **help > install a new software** option
2. Tried mvn install using cmd
3. Tried uncommenting proxy tag in setting.xml file
4. Tried 'https' instead of 'http' in proxy tag in settings.xml file
5. Tried reinstalling eclipse

and maybe more..

**After mvn package**

```
E:\Workspace\springpractice>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.anuragr07:springpractice >--------------------
[INFO] Building springpractice 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom

**Downloaded all the plugins**

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.831 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-01T23:52:35-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am really frustrated and searching for solutions from past 24 hours. Please help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your `pom.xml`, there might be something wrong with your pom file as the error message reads that no goal is specified for the build. @Anurag Rawal

Comment: Yes sure, I have shared it. Can you please check it. @Ananthapadmanabhan

Comment: The build is failing because you haven't provided any `build` goal in your pom file.

Comment: Try the following. 1. Close the eclipse first - try to work in CMD and configure maven there. Remove setting.xml in your user directory if the file exists there. 2. Download Maven from official site. 3. Add the path to %MVN_HOME%\bin to the Path env. variable in windows. 4. open CMD and cd to the folder where you have a pom.xml. 5. Type: mvn package. 6. Post the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [specifying goal in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852950/specifying-goal-in-pom-xml)

Comment: Did that but real issue is plugins. @leopal

Comment: I think it worked @MarkBramnik

Comment: First try to build your project from plain command line ..via `mvn clean package`...

Comment: Thanks @MarkBramnik it did work. It did not worked on the project I have created earlier but when I tried creating new project and it was all okay with no errors. I think there was some issue with the settings.xml file. Can you refer me some links or resources to grab some maven and spring concepts.

Comment: Now I am getting another error, which is 'cound not resolve archetype' when I create a new project using an archetype. But it is working with normal  project in which I skip archetype. Can you suggest something? @MarkBramnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the settings.xml file and the solution is:-

1. Close the eclipse first - try to work in CMD and configure maven there. Remove setting.xml in your user directory if the file exists there.
2. Download Maven from official site.
3. Add the path to %MVN_HOME%\bin to the Path env. variable in windows.
4. open CMD and cd to the folder where you have a pom.xml.
5. Type: mvn package. 6. Post the output.

Thanks to @MarkBramnik

Answer (score 0):

you have to designate maven goal.
in pom.xml, insert that

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

</build>
```

I guess there is no defaultGoal in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The given ERORR is the cause of the default goal.

### ERROR No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:.

Resolution:

Specify any goal in your run configuration for maven build like clear, compile, install, package.

install
...

Could you please refer to the given steps?

- Right click on your project.
- Click 'Run as' and select 'Maven Build'
- Edit Configuration window will open.
- write any goal but your problem specific write 'package' 
  in Goal text box.
- Click on 'Run'